# SwiftUI: Preload View without displaying

Tags: uiview, swiftui, preload, skscene

I'd like to "preload" a view (including a SKScene) to gather the bounds of the display area of this scene.
The size information is needed to precompute additional data, the computation should be done in the background while displaying the home screen (different to the screen containing the SKScene).

Q: It it possible to preload a view and if so, how?

Thanks,
J.

Comment: Why do you need to preload the next view? Why not just do the calculations on the Home Screen and pass them as as parameters to the next screen?

Comment: The home screen is different to the screen with the SKScene. The screen with the SKScene includes some SwiftUI Components, therefore the area that includes the SKScene is different and not the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution. I switch to the screen directly after application start, gather the needed information and immediately switch to the home screen.
I use the method onAppear() and a global variable as a flag to avoid a second automatic return to the home screen.